# Gambler's ruin and coin toss

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

#### Edit 3. Fixed question to be more clear and include current solution

## Problem

Two players player 1 and player 2 plays a game of fair coin flipping. Player 1 starts with $A$ coins and Player 2 with $B$ coins. Let $P_n$ defines the probability of player 1 winning all coins in a game when player 1 has $n$ coins. Find the recurrence relation of $P_n$ and then find its closed formula.

This formula can then be used to know the probability of player 1 winning if he has, i.e. twice the coins player 2 has.

## Solution?

I know that $P_0 = 0$, because if she has $0$ coins, then she can't win, what about $P_{A+B}?$

$$P_n = 0.5P_{n+1} + 0.5P_{n-1}$$
Which gives the characteristic equation: $$x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2=0 \implies x=1\ (double\ root)$$
This can then be put into the general solution for linear homogenous recurrence relations:
$P_{hn} = C_1+nC_2$ and here I'm stuck once again. To find these two values I'd need two boundary points

Comment: I changed the whole post to be a lot more clear what I need help for.

Comment: The other boundary condition is $P_{A+B}=1$.

Comment: @XMLParsing: This question was duplicated a few hours later, which I provided a [solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/936778/137524) to before I noticed this earlier question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have k coins. Then after the first flip, you are equally likely to have k-1 or k+1.

So the probability of winning all from a starting point of $k$ is $P_k = 0.5 P_{k+1} + 0.5 P_{k-1}$

It's fairly easy from here to verify that $P_k = k/(n_1+n_2)$.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. One question, does $P_k$ denote the probability of winning all coins, or does it denote the probability of losing all coins?

Comment: Edited to clarify!

Comment: Thank you for you help. You claim it's fairly easy to verify the formula. However, I'm puzzled because I can't seem to iterate it, as I only have one boundary $P_0 = 0$ and I can't solve it like a normal recurence relation either. Have any idea on how to solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: The other boundary is $P_{n_1+n_2}=1$ - if you have all the coins already, success is certain. Then the standard way to tackle these recurrence relations is to solve the characteristic polynomial $t = 0.5t^2 + 0.5$ - this has a repeated root of 1 so your general solution is $P_k = A1^k + Bk1^k$ for some $A, B$